# unable to install R package "marmap"

Tags: dependencies, r

I am trying to install the R package `marmap` on my workstation at the uni. I am running Xubuntu LTS 14.04.5, kernel version 4.4.0-45, with RStudio Version 0.99.903 and R version 3.3.1. When installing the `marmap` package, there is a a lot (!) of information buzzing by, ending with

```
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (igraph)
* installing *source* package ‘gdistance’ ...
** package ‘gdistance’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (gdistance)
ERROR: dependency ‘ncdf4’ is not available for package ‘marmap’
* removing ‘/home/francesc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/marmap’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘marmap’ had non-zero exit status
```

Here, I figured that "non-zero exit status" means, that it didn't install correctly. So, I'd install the package `ncdf4` first, only to be confronted with the following:

```
install.packages("ncdf4") Installing package into ‘/home/francesc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’ 
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ncdf4_1.15.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 119570 bytes (116 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 116 KB

* installing *source* package ‘ncdf4’ ...
** package ‘ncdf4’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure.ac: starting
checking for nc-config... no
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error, nc-config not found or not executable.  This is a script that comes with the
netcdf library, version 4.1-beta2 or later, and must be present for configuration
to succeed.


If you installed the netcdf library (and nc-config) in a standard location, nc-config
should be found automatically.  Otherwise, you can specify the full path and name of
the nc-config script by passing the --with-nc-config=/full/path/nc-config argument
flag to the configure script.  For example:

./configure --with-nc-config=/sw/dist/netcdf4/bin/nc-config

Special note for R users:
-------------------------
To pass the configure flag to R, use something like this:

R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-nc-config=/home/joe/bin/nc-config" ncdf4

where you should replace /home/joe/bin etc. with the location where you have
installed the nc-config script that came with the netcdf 4 distribution.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ncdf4’
* removing ‘/home/francesc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/ncdf4’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ncdf4’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpC5Luhz/downloaded_packages
```

When I tried to run the suggested command in a terminal:

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-nc-config=/home/francesc/bin/nc-config" ncdf4
```

The response was the following:

```
~$ sudo R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-nc-config=/home/francesc/bin/nc-config" ncdf4
[sudo] password for : 
Warning: invalid package ‘ncdf4’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
```

Now I am a bit at a loss, can anyone point me in the right direction ? Much appreciated !

PS Earlier this month, I found and applied a super-simple command in the command line, to install an R package, but I can't seem to find anymore. Literally a five-word string, which faultlessly installed an R package from the terminal. Is there an easy way to install R packages from the command line ?

Francesc

Comment: FYI, the reason your `R CMD INSTALL ...` command failed is probably that `R CMD INSTALL ncdf4` expects you to either pass it a `.tar.gz` file of the ncdf package, or to pass it a folder name that contains the source code of the package you want to install.  I'm guessing you did not have a folder `/home/francesc/ncdf4` containing the ncdf4 source code, hence the "invalid package" error message.

Comment: Thanks for the comment drammock, I've come across it another time and implemented your advice. Live and learn :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ncdf4` require system libraries be installed, so you have a couple of options:

1. Install the pre-built `ncdf4` package from the repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install r-cran-ncdf4
   ```

   This will automatically pull in the required system dependencies.
2. Or, you can install the system dependencies explicitly:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install netcdf-bin
   ```

   Then, install the R package:

   ```
   > install.packages('ncdf4')
   ```

Comment: Hi amc, thanks for your reply ! I installed everything netcdf I could find with Synaptic. After that, both ncdf4 and marmap were installed in seconds. Unbelievable ! I have been fussing around for too long... thanks again !

Comment: Consider this one solved.

Comment: Done ! Your answer helped insofar that I realised I needed to install all these other packages/applications to continue. Also, your code snippet `sudo apt-get install r-cran-ncdf4` jogged my memory for how to install R packages from the terminal/command line, as this sometimes works better than doing from within RStudio. Thanks again !